# How to use same cached page for different urls in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I have two urls that basically renders the same page. The minor differences can be easily executed via javascript, based on the `location.href`. Anyway, even when the routes point to the same `controller#action`, the second route is not using the page cached by the former. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a interesting requirement in my website opposite to you -- Different pages can be returned from a same url because of different themes. So I came up a solution called "anonymous cache", and I make my own cache key including the extra parameters. But I think this solution can give you some clues.

```
module AnonymousCache
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def caches_page_for_anonymous(*pages)
      before_filter :check_cache_for_anonymous, :only => pages
      after_filter :cache_for_anonymous, :only => pages
    end
  end
  def check_cache_for_anonymous
    return unless perform_caching 
    return if logged_in? 
    path = anon_cache_path

    if content = Rails.cache.read(path)
      send_data(content,
        :type => 'text/html;charset=utf-8', :disposition => 'inline')
      return false
    end
  end
  def cache_for_anonymous
    return unless perform_caching
    return if logged_in? 
    path = anon_cache_path
    @expires_in ||= 1.hour
    self.class.benchmark "Cached page for guest: #{path}" do
      Rails.cache.write(path, response.body, :expires_in => @expires_in.to_i)
    end
  end
  protected :check_cache_for_anonymous
  protected :cache_for_anonymous
  private
    def anon_cache_path()
      path1 = File.join(request.host, current_theme, request.path)
      q = request.query_string
      path1 = "#{path1}?#{q}" unless q.empty?
      path1
    end
end
```

`anon_cache_path` method is where I make canonical key for the page cache. You can see I includes `current_theme` in it.

You can copy this and changes `anon_cache_path` according to your requirements.